# Safest way to store variable using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, variables

I'm trying to figure out the best practice, as well as safest, way to store a variable with javascript for a web app I'm developing.

I have pages that are generated using php, $_GET and mod_rewrite. They are generated from the id that's given through the url. For example: http://example.com/1125/ (because of mod_rewrite what's actually happening is: http://example.com?id=1125). The php takes $_GET['id'] and retrieves information from the database in accordance the id given, etc... you get the gist.

The problem I'm having is, I have a form on that page where a user can post a question, which is sent via ajax. And I don't know the best way to store the page's id ($_GET['id']).

Right now, I have the id stored in a hidden input within the form (for example: " />). And when the form is submitted to the server and php takes a look a $_POST, it contains ["id"] => 1125. That's how I'm sending the page's id when a question is submitted via the form in the page.

The reason I think that's not secure is, anyone can edit the html (for example through Chrome's inspect element) and change the hidden input's (id) value to any other id.

So my question is, what's the safest way I can store that id with javascript, so when that question form is submitted, It can safely send the correct id to the server? Or any other suggestions thought out with best practice methods?

Comment: You could pass it using the SESSION_ array from the originating page. Then you don't have to store it in a hidden field.

Comment: Not sure why you want JS to store the id in this case! Why not let php handle the whole process?

Comment: I thought that already, but if someone visits http://example.com/1111/ then opens another tab and goes to another page e.g. http://example.com/2222/ the $_SESSION id variable will change to 2222, which wont change if they return to the tab with the id of 1111 and submit a question ($_SESSION['id'] will still contain 2222 rather than 1111).

Comment: There is no safe way to store it on the client side. You'll have to do validation on the server.

Comment: Any idea how I can use php to validate what id they're using when they submit the question form? (fyi, using ajax)

Answer (score 0):

You only just need to validate the `id` in the php page that receives the ajax, if the `id` is valid and the user has permission to use it, then it's ok and it doesn't matter if he changed it through chrome or whatever, but you need to validate because if he changed it for the `id` that belongs to other user then you have to detect that and error out in that case.

This is just a matter of validate your input according to the priveleges in your application.

Comment: I wanted to avoid a user who has the premissions to post a question on page-id 1111 or page-id 2222 post a question for id 2222 on page id 1111 by changing the html. Make sense haha?